# How to embed SQL queries into R Markdown to include it in Google sites?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm creating my first portfolio (using Google Sites) for data analytics. I know that we can embed html code into Google sites and I have successfully done that using R Markdown for my data visualization case study. But now I'm trying to figure out a way to include SQL queries (from BigQuery) into this site (Google Sites) so that I can show future employers that I'm familiar with SQL as well.

I have setup and obtained API key, OAuth Client Id and secret, and the required JSON file from BQ, following instructions mentioned in this link (https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/get-api-credentials.html#get-a-google-cloud-platform-project). Now I don't know what to do next to run SQL queries into R/R Markdown to get the html codes for the same so that it can be copied into the Google site. Any help from anyone on this will be really appreciated.